# memory space required for char definition

Tags: c, arrays, memory, char

```
char txt[20] = "Hello World!\0";
```

How many bytes are allocated by the above definition?
Considering one `char` occupies 1 byte, one `int` 2 byte.
Note that there is only one `"`, and `\0` at the end.
How to calcultate many many bytes the above definition has occupied?

Comment: Ehh? strlen, maybe? Gotta take care of the null-s though.

Comment: The array `txt` takes up 20 bytes, no matter the contents of it. Also note that on almost all systems (32 and 64 bits) an `int` is 32 bits (four bytes), and have been like this since the late 1980's.

Comment: Downvoted because answer can be found in any C book. This seems like a "do my homework for me" -question without any effort to solve from the asker.

Comment: @user694733 this is an conceptual question not any home work

Comment: By the way, the C compiler will automatically add a terminator to all string literals and all arrays initialized with string literals. For this example, you don't need to add it explicitly.

Comment: Where does `int` type and its size come into the game? Your question does not contain any variable of type `int`.

Comment: yes that is true   @Gerhardh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Statement `char txt[20]="Hello World!\0"` comprises actually two parts, a definition part and an initialization part. `char txt[20]`, the definition part, tells the compiler to reserve 20 elements of size of character (in this case 20 bytes), regardless of the content with which you will initialize the array later on. The initialization part `="Hello World!\0"` then "prefills" the reserved memory with the characters of literal `Hello World!\0`. Note that it is actually not necessary to write `\0` explicitly in the string, since string literals are by itself terminated by the `\0`-character. So you should write `char txt[20]="Hello World!"`. It is OK if the length of the string literal is smaller than the memory allocated; If the length of the string literal used for initializing exceeds the length of the array, you get at least a compiler warning.

Note, however, that if you write `char txt[]="Hello World!"`, the length of the memory reserved will be exactly the length of the initial string literal.

Concerning array initialization, you might confer to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization). Concerning the discussion on "variable definition" versus "variable declaration", I find this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1410632/2630032) very helpful.

Comment: Don't forget the variable *definition* part.

Comment: Variable definition? What? @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: @tilz0R A variable need both to be *declared* and to be *defined*. A declaration tells the compiler what type the variable have, and its name. A definition is what tells the compiler to actually allocate space for the variable. Most variable declarations are also definition (like in the question), but it is possible to separate the two.

Comment: Ok that was misunderstanding part. My understanding of your comment was that you were trying to say that variable name requires additional memory which is in fact for sure not true. Now it is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Anything which goes inside the double quotes in C is considered as string with null termination in the end. You don't have to add \0 in the end.

You can use `strlen(arr)+1`to get the size of char. Here +1 because strlen doesn't count null termination.